# Icons are broken

Tags: windows, desktop, desktop-icons

I have a problem after installing a program to remove the arrows on the desktop icons. Instead of removing the arrows, all my icons do not appear properly. It is like half is showing. It is hard to explain, and would like to add a screenshot, but I do not know how.

Please help! I am not very experienced, and hope to get some help, that is not too complicated. :-)

Comment: The link to the image seems to be broken - just add a link to it somewhere and someone with sufficient rep will add it inline.

Comment: Did you uninstall the program you in installed?

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned above, first uninstall the program that did this
2. In Windows Explorer, press Alt if the menu is not visible, then go to Tools menu / Folder Options / View tab, select **Show hidden files, folders and drives** and click on OK
3. Since you haven't specified which version of Windows you're using,

   a. In **Windows XP** go to `%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data` or `C:\Documents and Settings\<User Name>\Local Settings\Application Data` and delete the **IconCache.db** file

   b. In **Windows Vista/7** go to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local` or `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local` and delete the **IconCache.db** file
4. Restart your PC and see if the problem's fixed after rebuilding your system's icon cache